# How do I delete a specific portion of a line that begins after a character of my choice?

Tags: python, php, string, text

I would like a useful method or script to delete a certain portion of several lines, but on the condition that I choose the letter at which the deletion begins.
For example, in the following text

- TestTest | This Is for Test
- TestTest | This Is for Test
- TestTest | This Is for Test

I want to choose the symbol | To delete all the lines after it, so that the text becomes like this

- TestTest |
- TestTest |
- TestTest |

Comment: You tagged both Python and PHP on this question -- is this not part of a particular existing script?  If this is something you need as a stand-alone tool, I'd suggest either `sed` or `cut` rather than writing your own script.  E.g. try `echo "TestTest | This Is for Test" | sed -e "s/|.*/|/"`

Answer (score 0):

I will show an example using split. Though I'm sure many will share some amazing usage of regex. This is clean and simple.

```
a_string = "TestTest | This Is for Test"
split_string = a_string.split("|", 1)
substring = split_string[0]
```

**output**

```
TestTest
```